# How to pick a name for a controller in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, naming-conventions

For starters let me say that I know that the name of the controller should ends with `Controller` to fit nicely into the framework. But I would like to know what do you usually put before the Controller part?

For example, in unit tests it is quite straightforward, before `Test` you put the name of the class which you want to test. So in Symfony2 I should put the name of the entity which is the central object of interest in this controller? Maybe there are different approaches? I am interested in your experience, do you stumble across some pros or cons while taking one or other path? Or maybe "it doesn't matter"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can name your controller as you wish, and there is no real convention about that.

- I usually call my controller with the name of the main entity that it deals with. For example, if I have a NewsBundle with entities News and Comment, I call my controller NewsController (even if I manipulate comments in it).
- If I have only one controller in my bundle, I name it with the name of the bundle.
- You can have several "modules" inside a bundle, you usually have one controller for each "module": example with [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle): they have modules Security, Resetting, Registration, etc. Each of these modules have a dedicated controller and folder in the Resources/views folder.

Comment: Oh, so it's much less fine grained that I thought then. Don't you end up with a really huge controller class that is difficult to manage?

Comment: @JohnM2 You only end up with huge controllers if you allow that to happen. It's all up to you.

Comment: Exactly, when you have a too big controller, just split it in 2 or 3 parts that fit well. Really, it's up to you.

Comment: I think you can put controllers inside a folder (i know in Zend you can) for better overall application control (if you wish).